# MDX Calculated measure which makes sum of distinct values

Tags: sql-server, ssas, mdx, business-intelligence, analysis

I have weird problem which I'm trying to resolve. My fact table looks like follow:

```
CaseID | ClientID | PaymentDate|ToPay   | Paid
1      |     1    | 2015-01-01 |1000    |100
1      |     1    | 2015-02-01 |1000    |200
1      |     1    | 2015-03-01 |1000    |300
2      |     1    | 2015-01-01 |2000    |100
2      |     1    | 2015-02-01 |2000    |400
2      |     1    | 2015-03-01 |2000    |150
```

What I'm trying to do is create 2 measures:
`Sum(ToPay)`
`Sum(Paid)`

What is the problem?

In the result set I should get values like this:
Client: 1 To Paid: 3000, Paid: 1250

Which means that sum(ToPay) will be calculated as distinct values for specific client and case.

It is possible to create such query in `MDX`? If yes then how?

Comment: SSAS Multidimensional or Tabular?

Comment: Counting the distinct ToPay values seems very dangerous. Is it never possibly that a client owes two separate $1000 payments? How would you distinguish those two separate payment?

Comment: It is but then we will have two different CaseID's. Business case is connected with hire-purchase. One client may have two credit's and I need to know how much he has already repaid. I would like to have it in one table - for now I created query in DSV to get distinct values but I'm preety sure it's possible to solve it in MDX.

Comment: I'm assuming Multidimensional because you mentioned the DSV. I would recommend you continue doing this in the DSV because Multidimensional isn't really designed for leaf level calculations like this. To do it properly you will have to find distinct CaseID values then sum the ToPay values over those CaseID distinct values.

Answer (score 0):

Ok - I tried to model your situation with the `MS` cube `AdvWrks`

Here is the situation where all are summed:

```
WITH 
  MEMBER [Date].[Calendar].[All].[x] AS 100 
  MEMBER [Date].[Calendar].[All].[y] AS 200 
  MEMBER [Date].[Calendar].[All].[z] AS 200 
  SET [blah] AS 
    {
      [x]
     ,[y]
     ,[z]
    } 
  MEMBER [Measures].[xx] AS 
    Sum
    (
      [blah]
     ,[Measures].[Internet Sales Amount]
    ) 
SELECT 
  {[Measures].[xx]} ON 0
FROM [Adventure Works];
```

Result is 500.

To pull out the sum of just distinct values I've used `Filter`, it depends on the set being in order so also needed to use the `Order` function:

```
WITH 
  MEMBER [Date].[Calendar].[All].[a] AS 100 
  MEMBER [Date].[Calendar].[All].[x] AS 50 
  MEMBER [Date].[Calendar].[All].[y] AS 200 
  MEMBER [Date].[Calendar].[All].[z] AS 200 
  SET [blah] AS 
    {
      [a]
     ,[x]
     ,[y]
     ,[z]
    } 
  MEMBER [Measures].[xx] AS 
    Sum
    (
      Filter
      (
        Order
        (
          [blah]
         ,[Measures].[Internet Sales Amount]
        ) AS x
       ,
          (
            x.CurrentMember
           ,[Measures].[Internet Sales Amount]
          )
        <> 
          (
            x.Item(
            x.CurrentOrdinal)
           ,[Measures].[Internet Sales Amount]
          )
      )
     ,[Measures].[Internet Sales Amount]
    ) 
SELECT 
  {[Measures].[xx]} ON 0
FROM [Adventure Works];
```

Result is 350.

Comment: @GregGalloway I'm guessing there must be a simpler way!! ...?

Answer (score 0):

If you do take Greg Galloway's advice, great for you. Otherwise, another good `MDX` challenge!

Here's what you can do.

First sort the set in its natural order.

Next, count the measure `[To Pay]` only for those cases where either the current member in the set is not the same as the previous member OR if it is the very first member(in which case the current will always not be the same as previous member)

```
with set [Client&Case] as
order
     (
        [Fact].[ClientID].[All].children * [Fact].[CaseID].[All].children,
        [Fact].[ClientID].currentmember.name + "" + [Fact].[CaseID].currentmember.name
     )


member measures.[Actual - To Pay]  as 
sum
    (
     [Client&Case],
      iif
      (    
        not([Client&Case].item([Client&Case].currentordinal-1) is [Client&Case].item([Client&Case].currentordinal-2)) 
           --current not same not as previous
        or [Client&Case].currentordinal = 1 --the first member!
       ,[Measures].[To Pay]
       ,0
      )
    )

select 
{measures.[Paid], measures.[Actual - To Pay]} on 0,
[Client&Case] on 1
from [Your Cube]
```

**From Adventure Works:**

```
    with set [Category&Country] as
    {
    ([Product].[Category].&[3], [Customer].[Customer Geography].[Country].&[Australia]),
    ([Product].[Category].&[3], [Customer].[Customer Geography].[Country].&[Australia]),
    ([Product].[Category].&[4], [Customer].[Customer Geography].[Country].&[Australia]),
    ([Product].[Category].&[4], [Customer].[Customer Geography].[Country].&[Australia]),
    ([Product].[Category].&[4], [Customer].[Customer Geography].[Country].&[Australia])
    }

    member measures.TotalInternetSales as
    sum([Category&Country],[Measures].[Internet Sales Amount])

    member measures.[ActualInternetSales]  as 
    sum
        (
         [Category&Country],
          iif
          (         
            not([Category&Country].item([Category&Country].currentordinal-1) is [Category&Country].item([Category&Country].currentordinal-2)) 
            or [Category&Country].currentordinal = 1
           ,([Category&Country].currentmember, [Measures].[Internet Sales Amount])
           ,0
          )
        )

    select 
    {measures.TotalInternetSales, measures.[ActualInternetSales]} on 0
    from [Adventure Works]
```

Hope it works.